# Implementing automatic logout in silverlight and wcf due to user inactivity

Tags: wcf, silverlight, logout

I have a WCF web-service and a Silverlight app displaying data from that service. In my service I'd like to implement automatic logout of the user, if no service methods were invoked during a period of time (for example 20 minutes).

I'm thinking about smth like that:

```
Dictionary<User,TimeSpan> Inactivity
```

When a service method is invoked i reset the TimeSpan. But what will happen, if 20 minutes pass, and I call the Logout method (which clears all User caches), and suddenly the User returns from lunch)) and presses a button in his Silverlight app? Obviously he'll get an error. Is there any way to avoid this, or all my concept is wrong? Maybe there's a better way to logout the user automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20 mins passes, Logout method runs, user's redirected to a login page, user comes from lunch, sees a login page with a message that his session has expired, enters username/password, logs in.

Comment: the problem is, that the logout method is called in a web-service and not on the client. and there's no way to notify the client about that

Comment: Well, then you have 2 options: a) use messaging (Kaazing, Nirvana, etc.) to notify client about logout b) have a periodic session check in the client that would query the service if it's still logged in + make client handle the security exception thrown by any of your services once client's session is expired.